# show that the differential equation $f''(z) = zf(z)$ has a unique entire solution for $f(0) = f'(0) = 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

This is a problem from Berkeley Problems in Mathematics (2004 edition, pg 67, 5.2.3)

The solution starts with using the Maclaurin expansion around $0$

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n z^n$$

and

$$a_0 = 1, a_1 = 1, a_2 = 0, a_k = \dfrac{a_{k-3}}{k(k-1)}$$

and then use induction for $k \ge 1$ to get,

$$ 
a_{3k} = \prod_{j=1}^{k} \dfrac{1}{3j(3j-1)}, \\  
a_{3k+1} = \prod_{j=1}^{k} \dfrac{1}{3j(3j+1)}, \\ 
a_{3k+2} = 0 
$$

I don't get the step where they evaluated $a_k$? Any hints?

For sake of completion, let me add the complete solution here:

Since $\lim_{k \to \infty} \dfrac{a_{3k+3}}{a_{3k}} = 0,$ the series $\sum a_{3k}z^{3k}$ has infinite radius of convergence and same argument holds for the series with index $3k+1$, Thus $f$ has an infinite radius of convergence which proves the uniqueness of the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the differential equation:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+2)(k+1)a_{k+2}z^k = f''(z) = zf(z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{k-1}z^k.$$
Comparing coefficients, we have
$$a_{k+2} = \frac{a_{k-1}}{(k+1)(k+2)}$$
for $k\ge1$. By writing $n=k+2$, the expression becomes
$$a_n = \frac{a_{n-3}}{n(n-1)}$$
for $n\ge3$, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

$$f''(z)-zf(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \big\{n(n-1)a_n z^{n-2}-a_nz^{n+1}\big\}=0,\forall n$$
Compare coefficients of $z^{m}$: $$(m+2)(m+1)a_{m+2}-a_{m-1}=0\\\implies a_k=\frac{a_{k-3}}{k(k-1)}$$ where we used $k=m+2$.